# Processing time clustering vs knn

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, knn

I'm working on the MNIST dataset, and was wondering about the processing time. I've performed the KMeans function with NN classifier and was able to receive around 116s processing time. Didn't get to implement this, but if I now perform a KNN algorithm on the respective clusters, will I get a slower or faster processing time, and why?

My thoughts are that since we increase the number of neighbors, the processing time will be much faster, but the error rate will increase. Am I wrong?

Comment: Apples and oranges? What "a KNN algorithm" are you referring to? What are you even trying to do?

Comment: If your question is "Does the processing time of a kNN query increase with increasing k?" then the answer is yes with all implementations I know of. It may only be marginally (at least the heap size for storing k best candidates increases) but can also be drastically (when the data is indexed with a spatial index structure and queries get less selective with increasing k).

Comment: How many types of kNN algorithms are there? As far as i know there is just one and that is, "kNN"?

Comment: @mnm kNN algorithm is a bit ambiguous in my opinion. Result-wise I agree there is only one (maybe with different voting strategies in the classification setting). However, implementation-wise there are large differences (e.g., sequential scan vs. indexed).